# How to Remove Custom Views?

Tags: android

I have several custom ImageViews which are added to a RelativeLayout dynamically.

```
public class EmptySoldierView extends ImageView {
        .
        .
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        EmptySoldierView.this.getAnimation().cancel();
        clickListener.onEmptySoldierClicked(player, regionID);
    }
}
```

And I am trying to remove all of these custom views like this:

```
@Override
public void onEmptySoldierClicked(Player player, int areaID) {
    player.addSoldier(areaID);
    drawSoldier(player, areaID);
    for (EmptySoldierView soldierView : emptySoldiers)
        ((ViewGroup) soldierView.getParent()).removeView(soldierView);
}
```

I know the correct way (documented) to remove views is using above approach. But it is not working in my case. I searched, read a lot of posts and struggled for three days before asking.

How to remove dynamically added custom views?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. The problem is Animation. View is removed from layout however animation is still on image. `animation.cancel()` is not enough. I added `setAnimation(null)` before removing View.